# Ubuntu 13 change drm_kms_helper poll param

Tags: kernel, graphics, 13.04, intel-graphics, intel

I had ubuntu for 3 years( since version 11).
Every version I had, had the Intel Graphics bug in it's kernel - randomly freezing mouse.
I fixed this problem using "echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll" (changing it from Y to N), as described in http://souriguha.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/how-to-solve-problem-with-thinkpadkslowd-kworker-on-linux-kernel-2-35-2-36/ .

I upgraded to version 13, and unfortunately this doesn't work (there is no /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf), I searched the web and tried adding the command above to /etc/rc.local, when I check the param it seem to be set to N, but still didn't solve the problem, so tried setting it to 0, and checked it, it turns back to Y somehow. The freezes still occurs :(

My kernel version is: Linux *****-ThinkPad-T400 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

What should I do? And on what version this bug will be fixed (It's really annoying since v11)?

Btw: If someone could explain to me what is the relation between polling and the mouse (I think it's the whole screen)?!

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me on Ubuntu 13.04:

```
sudo modprobe drm_kms_helper
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

Apparently the drm_kms_helper module isn't loaded by default on 13.04?  You may have to load it in your /etc/modprobe.d/ and then sett the poll parameter.

Comment: I just moved to openSuse with KDE and It seems to be a lot better than Ubuntu with KDE (more stable and bug-less), and I don't have this issue with drm_kms_helper.

But, Thanx a lot man :)